# Linux command to replace characters from stdin without '\n'

Tags: regex, linux, bash, awk, sed

I run a command like nc, and it output something like `{"foo1":"bar1"}{"foo2":"bar2"}` without line break continuously. 
I want to change the output as following:

```
{"foo1":"bar1"}
{"foo2":"bar2"}
```

I tried `nc -U /dev/mysocket | sed 's/}/}\n/g'`, but it doesn't work. Seems `sed` doesn't process input if it doesn't have '\n'.

In case of you don't have `nc` server which can output above sample. It's more like the following output by hello.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    while (1) {
            printf("{\"foo1\":\"bar1\"}");
            fflush(0);
            sleep(1);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

So the case is turned out to:
`gcc -o hello hello.c; ./hello | sed 's/}/}\n/g'` won't work. Seems sed doesn't even process input stream if there's no '\n'.
Any ideas on how to solve this issue? Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

You can use `awk`:

```
echo '{"foo1":"bar1"}{"foo2":"bar2"}' | awk -v RS='}' -v ORS='}\n' 'NF'
{"foo1":"bar1"}
{"foo2":"bar2"}
```

Or else, you can use this `sed`:

```
echo '{"foo1":"bar1"}{"foo2":"bar2"}' | sed $'s/}{/}\\\n{/g'
{"foo1":"bar1"}
{"foo2":"bar2"}
```

If you have `gnu sed` then following will also work:

```
echo '{"foo1":"bar1"}{"foo2":"bar2"}' | gsed 's/}{/}\n{/g'
{"foo1":"bar1"}
{"foo2":"bar2"}
```

However do note that your input is a JSON and you can use `jq` to get pretty print as:

```
echo '{"foo1":"bar1"}{"foo2":"bar2"}' | jq .
{
  "foo1": "bar1"
}
{
  "foo2": "bar2"
}
```

Comment: Thanks @anubhava. The `awk` command should work. However, in fact I am running command on Android. There's no awk command. In fact this case is more complicated. Use `echo` to simulate nc is not appropriate. I wrote a simple hello.c to simulate nc command and edited in question.

Comment: Android sed source code can be found here: `https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/toybox/+/master/toys/posix/sed.c`. I also tried `gnu sed` from unbutu with `./hello | sed $'s/}{/}\\\n{/g'` and still doesn't work.

Comment: I don't need sed source code. If you have access to install then simply install `awk` and get the job done. As mentioned `awk` worked with your  `hello` program as well.

Answer (score 0):

To insert a Line break character (\n) use it with `&` like below:

```
nc -U /dev/mysocket | sed 's/}/}&\n/g'
```